# Fetch all columns into one column oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How do i achieve to fetch all columns into one column.

I have below sample query

```
WITH da AS( 
SELECT 'a' col1, 'b' col2, 'c' col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '1' col1, '2' col1, '3' col1 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'x' col1, 'y' col1, 'z' col1 FROM dual
)
SELECT * FROM da;

//RESULTS

COL1|COL2|COL3|
----|----|----|
a   |b   |c   |
1   |2   |3   |
x   |y   |z   |
```

**But** what i want is the result to be as below with `|` as the delimiter.

```
ONE_COL|
-------|
a|b|c  |
1|2|3  |
x|y|z  |
```

My biggest problem is **i don't know the column names**, therefore i cant do as:

```
SELECT  col1||'|'||col2||'|'||col3 AS ONE_COL  FROM da;
```

how can i do this.

Comment: You don't know the names of the columns that you're selecting?

Comment: @JoanLaraGanau yes i dont know the column names .

Comment: Do you want something you can run interactively in a client like SQL Developer? Or do you need a procedural solution which is called by other programs?

Comment: @APC Any solution is welcome. we forgot pass to the DB  but we can pass query to the db to return result whereby the result is inserted in another db/table.

Comment: Well you can generate some dynamic SQL from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` but the whole situation seems odd.  What is the purpose of selecting data from a table you don't know the columns for?  How can it be useful if you don't know what it is?  Maybe look at SSIS or something?

Comment: @LoztInSpace i know the column names but they are renamed as, not the exact names. I thought i could do this as an urgent approach before i get the db credentials

Comment: If you know the table name then you can get the column names from Oracle's data dictionary and you can use _Native Dynamic SQL_ (NDS) to query the table.

Comment: Another thought - if you don't know the columns you (or Oracle) can't reliably know how to cast the values to varchar.  You might end up with some data that works and some that doesn't.  Again - you need to go to the schema but really I'd be rethinking the approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is just to demonstrate a way to achieve what you asked for. (Assuming I didn't misunderstand what you asked for.)

First some preparation.

1. Create the `DA` table (according to the sample data in your question).

```sql
create table DA (COL1 char(1), COL2 char(1), COL3 char(1));
```

2. Add rows to the table (again, according to the sample data in your question).

```sql
insert into DA values ('a','b','c');
insert into DA values ('1','2','3');
insert into DA values ('x','y','z');
```

3. I understand that you want to insert the data from table `DA` into another table, so I created a second database table according to what I understood from your question.

```sql
create table RESULT (ONE_COL char(5));
```

4. PL/SQL code that retrieves the names of the columns (assuming you know the table name) from the data dictionary, then creates a dynamic cursor to retrieve the values from that table (again in the format described in your question) and inserts the rows fetched by the dynamic cursor into a second database table (since this is your requirement as I understood it from your question).

```sql
declare
  L_COL  varchar2(128);
  L_CUR  sys_refcursor;
  L_ONE  char(5);
  L_SQL  varchar2(2000);
--
  cursor C_COLS is
    select COLUMN_NAME
      from USER_TAB_COLUMNS
     where TABLE_NAME = 'DA';
begin
  L_SQL := 'select ';
  open C_COLS;
  fetch C_COLS into L_COL;
  L_SQL := L_SQL || L_COL;
  while C_COLS%found
  loop
    fetch C_COLS into L_COL;
    if C_COLS%found then
      L_SQL := L_SQL || '||';
      L_SQL := L_SQL || '''|''||';
      L_SQL := L_SQL || L_COL;
    end if;
  end loop;
  close C_COLS;
  L_SQL := L_SQL || ' from DA';
  open L_CUR for L_SQL;
  loop
    fetch L_CUR into L_ONE;
    exit when L_CUR%notfound;
    insert into RESULT values (L_ONE);
  end loop;
  close L_CUR;
end;
```

5. Finally, after running the above PL/SQL code...

```sql
select * from RESULT;
```

which returns

```
ONE_C
-----
abc
123
xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Concat the dual columns within the with clause, that way you don't need know what the da columns are called.

```
WITH da AS( 
SELECT 'a' || '|' || 'b' || '|' || 'c' AS one_col FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '1' || '|' || '2' || '|' || '3' AS one_col FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'x' || '|' || 'y' || '|' || 'z' AS one_col FROM dual
)
SELECT * FROM da;
```

Comment: i don't know the column names

Comment: What table do you not know the columns of, 'da' or 'dual'?
I made the assumption that in your real use case 'dual' is an actual table and not dual.

Comment: I used that as a sample data. i send the query blindly and data is returned while inserted in another table. therefore i dont know the column names.

Answer (score 0):

The database knows the column names. So use the dbms_sql package and parse your sql.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-C96D5BAA-29A9-4AB5-A69E-E31228ECC9E9

There are many solutions to extract the data afterwards so I don't get your point why you think that you don't know any column names

Comment: if i have to know the column names. then i will have to first write a query that sends to the db and returns for me the column_names as one column. because i am not using an editor. The tool i am using i have to specify a column to insert the result, it is not a sql editor. i.e. i send query it returns while inserting the result in another table

Comment: The returned query contains the column names. So the problem you have is that with tool x you don't know how to reverse engeneer a query?

Comment: tool x has that limitation. since it is shared

Comment: You have to provide more information about your system setup in your question. Otherwise it's not possible to provide a good solution.